# Selenium Webdriver not respecting cookies or cached images

Tags: c#, selenium, webdriver, mstest

I am using Selenium (2.24) to generate unit tests (for the Visual Studio unit test framework). While using the C# WebDriver for FireFox, it appears that the browser which is fired up by the driver is not finding my website cookies via javascript (I have a javascript file included in the site that looks for cookies and lets me know if they are found). Also, it is not using the browsers image cache, and is always requesting new images from the server. This behavior does not happen when I run my site from the "normal" (not launched by Selenium) FireFox.

The strange thing is that calling the below code in my unit test DOES return my cookie (it just can't be found by my JavaScript)

```
driver.Manage().Cookies.GetCookieNamed("MyCookie");
```

How can I configure the driver to respect my cookies and use the browsers image cache? This functionality is key to testing my website.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By default the FirefoxDriver will create a new anonymous Profile each time it starts Firefox.  If you want it to use an exiting profile you need to tell it to.

In Java you do it like so:

```
ProfilesIni allProfiles = new ProfilesIni();
FirefoxProfile profile = allProfiles.getProfile("MyProfile");
WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver(profile);
```

I'm assuming there's something similar in C#

Comment: Okay, this is almost the same in C# driver, except its `FirefoxProfileManager` instead of `ProfilesIni`. Thank you for the tip. This worked for the cookies, but it still does not appear to be using the browser cache for the images. What am I missing?

Comment: No idea about the cache I'm afraid.  You could try starting Firefox by hand and then attaching WebDriver to this via the webdriver.firefox.useExisting property.  http://code.google.com/p/selenium/wiki/FirefoxDriver  I better point out this isn't recommended for production.

Comment: Have you had any luck getting `webdriver.firefox.useExisting` to work? It doesn't appear to do anything. If possible please provide a source code snippet of it's use.

Comment: This answer did help me fix the problem of reusing cookies, image cache not working but marking as answered because I think this is a bug in Selenium.

Comment: @DavidWebb Did you what is it for Chrome Browser. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76181546/selenium-cookies-not-retained-in-the-browser-after-starting-a-new-session

Answer (score 2):

For cookies: if cookie is marked as ["HTTP Only"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HttpOnly#HttpOnly_cookie) JavaScript on a page will not be able to see it.  As result any code that uses execution of JavaScript on the page will not see this particular cookie.

You can confirm it by using some HTTP debugger (i.e. Fiddler) to see if cookie is set with HttpOnly property. You also can check if running script on a page via dev tools or typing `javascript:alert(...)` in address bar can see the cookie (`document.cookie`)

Comment: The cookies are not HTTP only, they work fine via javascript outside of the Selenium WebDriver.